# is there any way to join sys,databases with sys.servername

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I Edited my question so it can be clearer,
In sys.server there is a row that called server_id,
I wanted to know if there is any name to get the database name from this server id,
I am working with replication and linked server so i wanted to make a query that takes all the server and get database names,
I dont need all the database that on the server.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of rows from the two tables?

Comment: I don't think sys.databases contains info for any linked or remote servers does it?  So you can just assume that all databases in sys.databases are associated with the the record in sys.servers where srvid = 0.

Comment: What data you are trying to get back from joining these two tables?

Comment: im not trying to join them, im trying to know if there is a way to get the database name from server id

Answer (score 0):

Taking your edit into consideration and removing my previous answer, I don't have an exact answer, but some additional metadata that might help: `sys.linked_logins`, `sp_linkedservers`.

Perhaps you could just get each linked server name and use `OPENQUERY` to query the `sys.databases` catalog on the remote server?

```
-- this would be done in some kind of loop:
DECLARE @linkedSvrName sysname = (SELECT TOP 1 name FROM sys.servers WHERE server_id > 0);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(' + @linkedSvrName + ', ''SELECT name FROM sys.databases'')';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

(I didn't have any linked server entries to test against to see if this would actually work as expected.)

Comment: i just edited my question, i don't need the databases name on the instance i'm using but a way to connect between the server_id or server name into database name that connected to it